# FlashPlayer Required Error

Tags: android, webview, flash

I have load a url in my Webview but that website required flash player plugin to run how can i involve flash player in my android app

my XML

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp" />
```

java code

```
 mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("That Url ");
```

Comment: Adobe discontinued Flash for Android years ago. Ideally, you remove Flash from your Web site, or you create a regular Android app rather than simply showing that site in a `WebView`. You are welcome to suggest to users that [they install Flash themselves manually](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/installing-flash-player-android-devices.html), but I do not know whether that will work with `WebView`.

Comment: their is no way to show the website in webview or in android app which run on adobe flash player???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adobe has stopped Flash for Android last year. Ideally, you should remove Flash from your site or create a regular Android app instead of just showing it in WebView. We recommend you to install Flash automatically.